# Slow Select Query In SqlServer returing 13 millions Records out of 60 million records from table

Tags: c#, sql-server, select, sqlperformance

We have a table with about 25 columns including one TXT_SUBSCRIBER_CELL_ID and LNGCASE_ID on which we have created Combined indexes.

When we query

```
SELECT          LNG_TOWER_ANALYZER_ID,
                LNG_UPLOAD_ID,
                DAT_START,
                ISNULL(LNG_DURATION, 0),
                ISNULL(INT_DIRECTION, 0),
                ISNULL(INT_CALL_DATA_TYPE, 0),
                TXT_SUBSCRIBER_NUMBER,
                TXT_OTHER_PARTY_NUMBER,
                TXT_CALLING_NUMBER,
                TXT_CALLED_NUMBER,
                ISNULL(TXT_SUBSCRIBER_IMSI, ''),
                ISNULL(TXT_SUBSCRIBER_IMEI, ''),
                ISNULL(TXT_SUBSCRIBER_CELL_ID, ''),
                ISNULL(TXT_SUBSCRIBER_BTS_ADDRESS, ''),
                ISNULL(TXT_SUBSCRIBER_LATITUDE, ''),
                ISNULL(TXT_SUBSCRIBER_LONGITUDE, ''),
                ISNULL(TXT_SUBSCRIBER_AZIMUTH_DEG, ''),
                ISNULL(TXT_SUBSCRIBER_NAME, ''),
                ISNULL(TXT_SUBSCRIBER_ADDRESS, ''),
                ISNULL(TXT_SUBSCRIBER_TOC, ''),
                DAT_SUBSCRIBER_ACTIVATION,
                ISNULL(TXT_OTHER_PARTY_NAME, ''),
                ISNULL(TXT_OTHER_PARTY_ADDRESS, ''),
                ISNULL(TXT_OTHER_PARTY_TOC, ''),
                DAT_OTHER_PARTY_ACTIVATION,
                ISNULL(TXT_ROAMING_NETWORK_COMPANY_NAME, ''),
                LNG_CASE_ID,
                ISNULL(TXT_OP_SP_NAME, ''),
                ISNULL(TXT_OP_COUNTRY_NAME, ''),
                ISNULL(TXT_OP_CITY_NAME, ''),
                0,
                ISNULL(BIT_YSN_ROAMING, 0),
                ISNULL(TXT_SUB_SP_NAME, ''),
                ISNULL(TXT_SUB_COUNTRY_NAME, ''),
                ISNULL(TXT_SUB_CITY_NAME, '')
FROM   TBL_TOWER_ANALYZER
WHERE  LNG_CASE_ID = 50
       AND TXT_SUBSCRIBER_CELL_ID IN ( '83_34493', '83_34492', '83_34491', '56_65413',
                                       '56_65412', '56_65411', '56_65364', '56_65363',
                                       '56_65362', '56_65361', '56_65153', '56_65152',
                                       '56_65151', '56_65133', '56_65132', '56_65131',
                                       '56_53013', '56_53012', '56_53011', '56_51463',
                                       '56_51462', '56_51461', '56_51383', '56_51382',
                                       '56_51381', '56_51053', '56_51052', '56_51051',
                                       '56_50193', '56_50192', '56_50191', '56_50053',
                                       '56_50052', '56_50051', '56_46853', '56_46852',
                                       '56_46851', '56_38933', '56_38932', '56_38931',
                                       '56_33703', '56_33702', '56_33701', '56_33473',
                                       '56_33472', '56_33471', '56_32443', '56_32442',
                                       '56_32441', '56_26113', '56_26112', '56_26111',
                                       '56_17143', '56_17142', '56_17141', '56_16803',
                                       '56_16802', '56_16801', '56_16193', '56_16192',
                                       '56_16191', '56_16083', '56_16082', '56_16081',
                                       '56_15533', '56_15532', '56_15531', '56_10284',
                                       '56_10283', '56_10282', '56_10281', '29_51483',
                                       '29_51482', '29_51481', '29_51423', '29_51422',
                                       '29_51421', '29_50943', '29_50942', '29_50941',
                                       '29_50913', '29_50912', '29_50911', '29_50383',
                                       '29_50382', '29_50381', '29_50373', '29_50372',
                                       '29_50371', '29_50343', '29_50342', '29_50341',
                                       '29_50333', '29_50332', '29_50331', '29_50323',
                                       '29_50322', '29_50321', '29_50313', '29_50312',
                                       '29_50311', '29_50303', '29_50302', '29_50301',
                                       '29_50293', '29_50292', '29_50291', '29_50283',
                                       '29_50282', '29_50281', '29_50263', '29_50262',
                                       '29_50261', '29_50253', '29_50252', '29_50251',
                                       '29_50243', '29_50242', '29_50241', '29_50234',
                                       '29_50233', '29_50232', '29_50231', '29_50223',
                                       '29_50222', '29_50221', '29_50203', '29_50202',
                                       '29_50201', '29_43603', '29_43602', '29_43601',
                                       '29_43483', '29_43482', '29_43481', '29_43103',
                                       '29_43102', '29_43101', '29_37203', '29_37202',
                                       '29_37201', '29_37113', '29_37112', '29_37111',
                                       '29_36974', '29_36973', '29_36972', '29_36971',
                                       '29_36964', '29_36963', '29_36962', '29_36961',
                                       '29_34993', '29_34992', '29_34991', '29_34983',
                                       '29_34982', '29_34981', '29_34723', '29_34722',
                                       '29_34721', '29_34483', '29_34482', '29_34481',
                                       '29_33863', '29_33862', '29_33861', '29_33353',
                                       '29_33352', '29_33351', '29_32563', '29_32562',
                                       '29_32561', '29_31633', '29_31632', '29_31631',
                                       '29_28683', '29_28682', '29_28681', '29_27933',
                                       '29_27932', '29_27931', '29_16933', '29_16932',
                                       '29_16931', '29_16773', '29_16772', '29_16771',
                                       '29_13013', '29_13012', '29_13011', '100_57213',
                                       '100_57212', '100_57211', '100_51103', '100_51102',
                                       '100_51101', '100_50986', '100_50985', '100_50984',
                                       '100_50983', '100_50982', '100_50981', '100_50216',
                                       '100_50214', '100_50213', '100_50212', '100_50211',
                                       '100_26223', '100_26222', '100_26221', '100_19823',
                                       '100_19822', '100_19821', '100_18363', '100_18362', '100_18361' )
       AND DAT_START BETWEEN '2013-05-24 01:00:00' AND '2013-05-24 12:59:59'
```

It takes about 50-55 seconds to complete the execution which is quite slow.

How can we Make it run fast.

[image: Execution Plan]

Comment: Use materialized views if you can constrain the result set at design time. Are you on SQL Server 2012? If so, I think that there are new column store APIs, http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/columnstore/.  Fetch only the columns that you actually need.

Comment: I use this query for not to show it on GUI but to insert this much data into new table which will be used in throughout my application. I am doing this because main table has about 60 millions records

Comment: Can you post the query execution plan?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers how can i post the plan here ??

Comment: @RajeevKumar - You can either post it as an image (use the image icon when editing your question to upload the image) or get the execution plan as text and post that.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Please look at the added execution plan

Comment: Do you need to get all records at once?

Comment: @IvanCrojachKaračić yup..

Comment: How many rows are actually returned? What if you put all the `TXT_SUBSCRIBER_CELL_ID` into an indexed `#temp` table? Does that help?

Comment: @MartinSmith It returns me 13 million records out of 60 million records from table

Comment: @RajeevKumar - According to the plan, no index is being used so my first point of action would be to create a covering index and verifying it's being used.

Comment: Why are you using DISTINCT?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers how can you say that index are not used. It shows the clustered index cost in execution plan with 78%

Comment: If you do a `SELECT ... INTO NewTable` then how long does a `SELECT * FROM NewTable` take? Wondering what the best case timing will be for you to transfer those 13 million rows.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers i have also tested that these indexes were not used ? what could be the reason for that ?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers If i reduced the no of `TXT_SUBSCRIBER_CELL_ID` in `IN` statment, indexed are used. Confusing ??

Comment: @RajeevKumar - *(Sorry, been in a meeting.)* There's only mention of a clustered index scan wich is essentially the same as a Table Scan *(when the PK is not used in the where clause)*. Is the statement any faster when you reduce the no of `in` elements *(you mention an index is being used when you reduce them)*

Comment: ... and you should definitly try @MartinSmith 's suggestion and try to keep his attention. No kidding.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers It actually comes quite fast if indexed are used usually in 5-6 seconds

Comment: @MartinSmith i could not get your suggestion to put all `TXT_SUBSCRIBER_CELL_ID` into #temp table. Can you please elaborate more on it..

Comment: @RajeevKumar - Well transferring and consuming 13 million rows is going to be quite time consuming in itself. This suggestion is to see how long that takes so you know what the absolute best case is going to be.

Comment: I would try creating a covering index like this `CREATE INDEX IX_TEST ON dbo.TBL_TOWER_ANALYZER (TXT_SUBSCRIBER_CELL_ID, DAT_START, LNG_CASE_ID) INCLUDE (... all other columns from your select... )` and see if it get's used *(don't forget to update statistics after creating the index)*. If it get's used, I would try to narrow the index down as much as possible.

Comment: My personal feeling is that indexing the constant list probably won't help in this case, it's a 13/60 ratio, so there's a strong bias to scanning the clustered index.  Worse, there's no productive way to convert this to a Merge Join (the only thing likely to be faster than a Hash Join against a small hash table).  What I'd like to know is the query IO and CPU statistics for this query?

Comment: Hmm, actually, how are you testing to get this time of 50-55 seconds?  Are you 1) doing an INSERT..SELECT to a #temp table, 2) doing a SELECT..INTO a #temp table, or 3) doing a SELECT to the grid in SSMS?  If the answer is #3, then that's likely to be the problem, try one of the other two methods and see how it runs.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. You can try using indexes.
> 2. Else you can try pagination in your UI which will limit the no of records to display...

Answer (score 0):

```
1-) Create a table [Filter_With] with only one field TXT_SUBSCRIBER_CELL_ID
2-) Populate this table with the TXT_SUBSCRIBER_CELL_ID's in the where clause.
3-) Join the Filter_With table with the TBL_TOWER_ANALYZER table.

4-) Define an index for the TXT_SUBSCRIBER_CELL_ID field in the TBL_TOWER_ANALYZER table.
5-) Define an index for the DAT_START field in the TBL_TOWER_ANALYZER.
```